# Creating a Basic Google Ads Campaign Report using Bigquery Transfer Data

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-data-transfer

I'm trying to create a basic campaign report using data from Bigquery's Google Ads Transfer service. I've been able to get cost, clicks, and impressions to match what's in the UI but conversions and conversion value is off. The value for Bigquery conversions doesn't match what's shown in the UI for All Conversions or Conversions by time either. Comparing attribution models also doesn't seem to get me the Bigquery figure.

For context, here is the SQL query I'm running in Bigquery.

```
Select 
    cmp.campaign_name as campaign_name,
    SUM(metrics_cost_micros)/1000000 as cost,
    SUM(metrics_conversions) as conv

From `[PROJECTID].[DATASET].ads_CampaignBasicStats_[MCCID]` as cs
left join `[PROJECTID].[DATASET].ads_Campaign_[MCCID]` as cmp USING (campaign_id, customer_id)
left join `[PROJECTID].[DATASET].ads_Customer_[MCCID` as acc USING (customer_id)

WHERE
  cmp._DATA_DATE = cmp._LATEST_DATE
  AND acc._DATA_DATE = acc._LATEST_DATE
  AND cs._DATA_DATE BETWEEN "2023-12-01" AND "2023-12-31"
  AND cs.customer_id = [ADACCOUNTID]

GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY cost desc
```

Is there something else I should be filtering by? How can I update my query to match what's shown in the UI?